# Add separate playpause button in Flexslider

Tags: javascript, imagebutton, playback, flexslider

I'm trying to add a playpause button to my flexslider presentation. Instead of the standard playpause button (inside the presentation) I would like to add a separate button somewhere else on the html-page.

Unfortunately I'm no expert in javascript. I can't seem to figure out how to make an element (say an image) somewhere else on my page behave like the play-pause button. How to connect it to the right script?

And if this is simply too difficult, just a play-button would also do... since the presentation pauses automatically when the visitors click next or previous.

Hope anybody can help us out!  Thanks

Comment: What's your current code?

Answer (score 0):

Create one button,

```
<input type='button' value='START SLIDESHOW' id='play-gallery' />
```

Then write js code for it,

put code in flexslide's function,

```
$('.flexslider').flexslider({
   animation: "slide",
        controlNav: false,
        pausePlay: false,
        slideshowSpeed: 4000,
        slideToStart: 0,
   start: function(slider) {
       var slideshowPlaying = true;
        $('#play-gallery').click(function() {
                    if($('ul.slides li').length > 1) {
                        if (slideshowPlaying == true) {
                            slideshowPlaying = false;
                            slider.pause();
                            $('#play-gallery').html('START SLIDESHOW');
                        } else {
                            slideshowPlaying = true;
                            slider.flexAnimate(slider.getTarget("next"));
                            slider.play();
                            $('#play-gallery').html('STOP SLIDESHOW');
                        }
                    }
                });
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

@HB Kautil +1 for your answer. But I had to change just two parts of your code. Would've added this as a comment but my "reputation" isn't there yet.

```
$('#play-gallery').val('START SLIDESHOW');
```

And

```
$('#play-gallery').val('STOP SLIDESHOW');
```

Other than that your answer did all the heavy lifting :)